# Email groups in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a little project and I have some SQL design issue with my data.

Let say I have 2 table in my DB:

```
Contacts
ID
name
privateemail1
privateemail2
office email
```

and I have Groups

```
ID
Groupname
```

What is the best way to link together them for distributions list that I would be able to use Groups in Groups as well?

If I do a members table with

```
ID
GroupID
ContactID
```

I can't see how to fit the embedded subgroups to the main.

Groups such as

Main groups e.g. Orchestra players; Singers
Sub groups e.g. Wind players, String players, male singers, female singers etc.

**Revised question:** the examples above can't cover all the variations... any groups can become sub or main, like Outlook Distribution list?

Just looking the comments, which I am very grateful, it would be nice to be able to see an CREATE, SELECT with all the groups and a DELETE example. That would bring more attention and hopefully more result.

I hope it isn't too dummy question but as a beginner I have spent some hours before I post this... Thanks for the helps in advance

Comment: thanks I was just about fixing the same issue.

Comment: where is this sub-group come from? is in the groups? or there is an another registered the details?

Comment: sub-groups are normal groups only the way that you can use any groups as main or sub.

Comment: You may also wish to further normalize the `Contacts` table, although this will likely work for your purposes.

Comment: can you explain a little bit more how to do that? I would learn from it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this with a dual-use table:

Table:groupMemberships

```
id
groupID
linktype
linkID
```

`linktype` can either be a text field ('user','group') which is nice and readable (if you're doing your own SQL access it may be worth the small performance hit) or you could use an INT field where (1,2) where each mean something to you.

To find all users in group 2:

```
SELECT linkID as userID FROM groupMemberships 
WHERE groupID=2 AND linktype='user';
```

To find all sub-groups:

```
SELECT linkID as groupID FROM groupMemberships 
WHERE groupID=2 AND linktype='group';
```

One of the problems with a dual table like this is when you want to -say- get all group users, but you have no idea how many sub-groups their might be.  If you can be sure there'll only be one level of sub-groups you can do:

```
SELECT linkID as userID FROM groupMemberships
WHERE groupID=2 and linktype='user'
UNION
SELECT sg.linkID as userID FROM groupMemberships g,groupMemberships sg
WHERE g.groupID=2 AND g.linktype='group' 
  AND sg.groupID=g.linkID AND sg.linktype='user'
```

If you have two tiers of sub-group, you'd need two unions and so on.  When you have `n` sub groups you need N unions which is a pain to write and not efficient.

An alternative solution is to keep your `contacts` and `groups` tables the same, and simply link contacts to groups - table `contactsGroups`

```
ID
groupID
userID
```

Now code side (outside of the database) when you add a user to a group (windplayers) you also add them to any parent groups (orchestra) automatically so the user actually gets two entries in the `contactsGroups` table.  This has the same stored information, but makes data-retrieval much easier.  You can even store this sub-group information in the database, although you already have it code-side with object inheritance or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I am going to build it and see if I can make it work.

Comment: Thanks Rudu, there are 'random' connections a person can be a singer and a horn player so this record will group to Orchestra, Wind, Orch Trustees, Hornists, Soloist, Singers, Choir member, Bass singer so I am not sure if I can do outside the coding.

Answer (score 3):

I think that what user911882 means is to have a schema like this:

```
Contacts
- ID
- name
- privateemail1
- privateemail2
- office
- email

Groups
- ID
- Groupname
- ParentGroupID **foreign key which references Groups.ID**

Memberships
- ID
- GroupID
- ContactID
```

Answer (score 0):

By understanding your question, you have to link a table to itself, then You can link to that table by **adding one more column in Groups** , lets **say Pid***, which will be of same datatype* as **that of Id** in the groups, then **make it as the foriegn key referencing ID in the same table**. I think it will solve your issue.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I didn't quite get it as a beginner but I am sure this is just as good as Rudu's answer. Thanks again for your effort. (sorry for my English)

Comment: Hi I keep looking the right solution. Could you write down the code for a create and select and delete SQL command? Thanks

Comment: Sure, For eg : you have orchestra players and singers in groups with id 1 and 2. then for inserting sub group , (violin(do know this is in orchestra, a guess)) ,                           query for insert is: insert into groups(groupname,Pid) values('Violin PLayers',1);  for selecting subgroups select groupname from groups where Pid=1; and for deleting delete from groups where Pid=1;   I think you understand.